# Eslint flags as not defined class member that acts as default argument value

Tags: typescript, eslint

Why after upgrading from:

```
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.13.0",
```

to:

```
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.0",
```

eslint has started to flag in the class below (written in Typescript) `currentPalette` as not defined [eslint(no-undef)] where it acts as default argument for `whichPalette`?

```
class Colormap {

    private currentPalette: string;

    getColors(numberColors: number, whichPalette = this.currentPalette): string[] {
        const colors = palette(whichPalette, numberColors);
        return colors.map((color) => `#${color}`);
    }
}
```

Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Well, it doesn't have a value

Comment: Initializing `currentPalette` does not solve the problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No way to make default argument work. So I returned to the good old way:

```
class Colormap {

    private currentPalette = "";

    getColors(numberColors: number, whichPalette?: string): string[] {
        const colors = palette(whichPalette ?? this.currentPalette, numberColors);
        return colors.map((color) => `#${color}`);
    }
}
```

This works and satisfy eslint.
Have a nice day!
mario